# Internet Explorer - Space Between Floated Divs

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, css-float

I've been running into a presentation issue with Internet Explorer.  The following simple block of code renders as I would expect it to in Safari, FireFox, Chrome, and Opera.  However it results in a noticeable **space** between the left and right floated DIV elements in both IE6 and IE7.

My question is: Is there a more **correct** way to achieve a float such that the same CSS works in both IE and the other browsers I've mentioned?  If not, what is the best approach for getting rid of the space in Internet Explorer?

Thanks, Matt

```
<style>
.left {
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    border: solid black 1px;
}

.right {
    width: 100px;
    margin-left:100 px;
    border: solid red 1px;
}
</style>

<div class="left">
    a
</div>
<div class="right">
    b
</div>
```

Since this is a community wiki. I thought I'd post the working code with the solution proposed below by Plan B.

```
<style>
        .left {
        width:100px;
        border: solid black 1px;
        float:left;
    }

    .right {
        width:100px;
        border: solid red 1px;
        float:left;
    }
    .clear {
        clear:both;
    }
</style>

<div class="left">
    a
</div>
<div class="right">
    b
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
c
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Float them both left, add the following after both divs:

```
 <div class="clear"></div>

 .clear { clear: both; }
```

That or use padding instead of margins.

Comment: This more or less worked.  Although I did only add the clearing DIV after the last element (where I wanted the line break)

Answer (score 1):

```
.body {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the double margin float bug. Described well here:

http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html

Comment: I don't think it's the double margin bug.  This is more like the 3px margin bug

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `display: inline` to floated divs. I believe this is an IE bug of adding more margins to floated elements. display: inline worked for me in the past. Hope this helps.

Comment: Floating an element automatically sets the display to block; you can't float an inline element.